# R: Identify highest ranking observation in groups of unequal size

Tags: r, grouping, ranking

The following code generates 2-level groups (by State within Test), then ranks each observation within each group based on ascending order of Grade. School is the tie-breaker.

```
School<-rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=10)
State<-rep(c("NY","NJ"),times=20)
Test<-rep(c("LSAT", "MCAT", "GRE","TOEFL","ACT"), times=8)
Grade<-trunc(rep((seq(from=500, to=600,length.out=4))))
dat<-data.frame(Test,State,School,Grade)
library(plyr)
dat<-ddply(dat, .(Test, State),transform,num=rank(Grade,ties.method="first"))
```

I convert the first-ranked item within each group to "lowest" using the following code:

```
dat$num[dat$num==1]<-"lowest"
```

In this sample df, the number of items per group is always 4, so I can convert the highest-ranked item in each group to "highest" using the following code:

```
dat$num[dat$num==4]<-"highest"
```

But how can I tag observations with "highest" when the number of rows is not constant across all groups? The following code creates a version of the df with two additional rows in one of the groups.

```
School<-rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=10)
State<-rep(c("NY","NJ"),times=20)
Test<-rep(c("LSAT", "MCAT", "GRE","TOEFL","ACT"), times=8)
Grade<-trunc(rep((seq(from=500, to=600,length.out=4))))
dat1<-data.frame(Test,State,School,Grade) 
dat1<-rbind(dat1,
     data.frame(Test="ACT",State="NJ",School="E",Grade=550),
     data.frame(Test="ACT",State="NJ",School="F",Grade=650))
library(plyr)
dat1<-ddply(dat1, .(Test, State),transform,num=rank(Grade,ties.method="first"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by checking which is the highest/lowest in each group and assign highest/lowest to those rows. Here, I use `ddply` to do that since you already use `plyr` in your code:

```
dat1 <- ddply(dat1, .(Test, State), transform, num=ifelse(num == max(num), "highest", 
                                                          ifelse(num == min(num), "lowest", num)))

> dat1
    Test State School Grade     num
1    ACT    NJ      A   533  lowest
2    ACT    NJ      B   600       4
3    ACT    NJ      C   533       2
4    ACT    NJ      D   600       5
5    ACT    NJ      E   550       3
6    ACT    NJ      F   650 highest
7    ACT    NY      A   500  lowest
8    ACT    NY      B   566       3
9    ACT    NY      C   500       2
10   ACT    NY      D   566 highest
11   GRE    NJ      A   600       3
12   GRE    NJ      B   533  lowest
13   GRE    NJ      C   600 highest
14   GRE    NJ      D   533       2
15   GRE    NY      A   566       3
16   GRE    NY      B   500  lowest
17   GRE    NY      C   566 highest
18   GRE    NY      D   500       2
19  LSAT    NJ      A   533  lowest
20  LSAT    NJ      B   600       3
21  LSAT    NJ      C   533       2
22  LSAT    NJ      D   600 highest
23  LSAT    NY      A   500  lowest
24  LSAT    NY      B   566       3
25  LSAT    NY      C   500       2
26  LSAT    NY      D   566 highest
27  MCAT    NJ      A   533  lowest
28  MCAT    NJ      B   600       3
29  MCAT    NJ      C   533       2
30  MCAT    NJ      D   600 highest
31  MCAT    NY      A   566       3
32  MCAT    NY      B   500  lowest
33  MCAT    NY      C   566 highest
34  MCAT    NY      D   500       2
35 TOEFL    NJ      A   600       3
36 TOEFL    NJ      B   533  lowest
37 TOEFL    NJ      C   600 highest
38 TOEFL    NJ      D   533       2
39 TOEFL    NY      A   500  lowest
40 TOEFL    NY      B   566       3
41 TOEFL    NY      C   500       2
42 TOEFL    NY      D   566 highest
```

If your data is large enough, you could also consider using `dplyr` or `data.table` which will be faster than `plyr`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` with `cut`

```
library(dplyr)
 dat1%>% 
 group_by(Test, State) %>%
 mutate(num=rank(Grade, ties.method="first"),
     Categ= cut(num, breaks=c(-Inf, min(num), max(num)-1, Inf), labels=c("lowest", "medium", "highest")))%>%
 arrange(Test,State,num)
 #Source: local data frame [42 x 6]
 #Groups: Test, State

 #    Test State School Grade num   Categ
 #1    ACT    NJ      A   533   1  lowest
 #2    ACT    NJ      C   533   2  medium
 #3    ACT    NJ      E   550   3  medium
 #4    ACT    NJ      B   600   4  medium
 #5    ACT    NJ      D   600   5  medium
 #6    ACT    NJ      F   650   6 highest
 #7    ACT    NY      A   500   1  lowest
 #8    ACT    NY      C   500   2  medium
 #9    ACT    NY      B   566   3  medium
 #10   ACT    NY      D   566   4 highest
 #11   GRE    NJ      B   533   1  lowest
 #12   GRE    NJ      D   533   2  medium
 #13   GRE    NJ      A   600   3  medium
 #14   GRE    NJ      C   600   4 highest
 #15   GRE    NY      B   500   1  lowest
 #16   GRE    NY      D   500   2  medium
 #17   GRE    NY      A   566   3  medium
 #18   GRE    NY      C   566   4 highest
 #19  LSAT    NJ      A   533   1  lowest
 #20  LSAT    NJ      C   533   2  medium
 #21  LSAT    NJ      B   600   3  medium
 #22  LSAT    NJ      D   600   4 highest
 #23  LSAT    NY      A   500   1  lowest
 #24  LSAT    NY      C   500   2  medium
 #25  LSAT    NY      B   566   3  medium
 #26  LSAT    NY      D   566   4 highest
 #27  MCAT    NJ      A   533   1  lowest
 #28  MCAT    NJ      C   533   2  medium
 #29  MCAT    NJ      B   600   3  medium
 #30  MCAT    NJ      D   600   4 highest
 #31  MCAT    NY      B   500   1  lowest
 #32  MCAT    NY      D   500   2  medium
 #33  MCAT    NY      A   566   3  medium
 #34  MCAT    NY      C   566   4 highest
 #35 TOEFL    NJ      B   533   1  lowest
 #36 TOEFL    NJ      D   533   2  medium
 #37 TOEFL    NJ      A   600   3  medium
 #38 TOEFL    NJ      C   600   4 highest
 #39 TOEFL    NY      A   500   1  lowest
 #40 TOEFL    NY      C   500   2  medium
 #41 TOEFL    NY      B   566   3  medium
 #42 TOEFL    NY      D   566   4 highest
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
setDT(dat1)
idx = dat1[, .I[c(which.min(num), which.max(num))], by="Test,State"]$V1
dat1[, num := as.character(num)][idx, num := c("lowest", "highest")]
#     Test State School Grade     num
# 1:   ACT    NJ      A   533  lowest
# 2:   ACT    NJ      B   600       4
# 3:   ACT    NJ      C   533       2
# 4:   ACT    NJ      D   600       5
# 5:   ACT    NJ      E   550       3
# 6:   ACT    NJ      F   650 highest
# 7:   ACT    NY      A   500  lowest
# 8:   ACT    NY      B   566       3
# ...
```

1. Convert `dat1` to data.table.
2. For each group in `Test,State`, get the row numbers, in `dat1` corresponding to each minimum and maximum value and store it in `idx`.
3. Convert `num` to character type first, and then we subset the rows using `idx` and change just those values of `num` with `lowest` and `highest` using R's *recycling* feature.

Note that if there's only one value for a group, then that'll be both minimum and maximum, in which case this solution will give you `highest` (the `lowest` will be replaced).

Answer (score 0):

This is a no packages version that is essentially the same as your original answer with an additional correction using ave() instead of 4. This was faster on the short data set provided, though maybe not on a bigger set.

```
# mark lowest
dat1[dat1$num == 1,'num'] <- 'lowest'

# mark highest
dat1[dat1$num == ave(x = dat1$num,list(dat1$Test,dat1$State),FUN = max),'num'] <- 'highest'
```